# OpenAPI: Refering to a java class Type

Tags: java, openapi

I need to create a class which contains 2 variable of type `Serializable`
I tried to write something like below in YAML file but it didn't pick java Serializable type.

```
Pair:
    type: object
    properties:
      a:
        $ref: '#/definitions/Serializable'
      b:
        $ref: '#/definitions/Serializable'

  Serializable:
    type: object
```

Can someone guide me on how to add a java class type in YAML file.

Comment: What tool do you mean when you say "it didn't pick java Serializable type"? (E.g. a specific server or client implementation.)

Comment: @Helen: I was refering to openapi generator maven plugin